# BoolVar for presenting precedence between IntervalVar variables in CP-SAT in google ortools

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I hope you are having a great day.

When I tried to code CP-SAT by using Google OR-Tools for implementing sequence-dependent setup times in scheduling, I couldn't find the way to present the precedence between two intervals as a boolean variable. For example, if Job 1 precedes Job 2 directly (Job 1 -> Job 2), I would like to force a boolean variable into 1. The reason is that, with the binary variable (named lit), I want to add a constraint for considering sequence-dependent setup time as shown below.

```
model.Add(start_vars[m][j2] >= end_vars[m][j1] + setup_matrix[m][j1[j2]).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
```

The intervals are defined as follows:

```
processing_itv_vars = [
    [model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(start=start_vars[m][j], end=end_vars[m][j], size=processingTimes[m][j], is_present=presence_vars[m][j], name="interval_machine{}_job{}".format(m, j))
     for j in jobs] for m in machines]
```

I declared it as an optional interval variable because I am now considering parallel machine scheduling problem that a job can be processed by any machine.

Is there any way to present a precedence between two intervals as a boolean variable>

For your information, I have attached a full code as shown below.

```
def cp_scheduling_ortools(prob:Instance):
jobs = [*range(0, prob.numJob)]
machines = [*range(0, prob.numMch)]
setup_matrix = prob.setup
processingTimes = prob.ptime
H = 100000

model = cp_model.CpModel()
presence_vars = [[model.NewBoolVar(name="presence_machine{}_job{}".format(m, j)) for j in jobs] for m in machines]
start_vars = [[model.NewIntVar(0, H, name="start_machine{}_job{}".format(m, j)) for j in jobs] for m in machines]
end_vars = [[model.NewIntVar(0, H, name="end_machine{}_job{}".format(m, j)) for j in jobs] for m in machines]
processing_itv_vars = [
    [model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(start=start_vars[m][j], end=end_vars[m][j], size=processingTimes[m][j], is_present=presence_vars[m][j], name="interval_machine{}_job{}".format(m, j))
     for j in jobs] for m in machines]
for m in machines:
    model.AddNoOverlap(processing_itv_vars[m])

presence_lit = [[[model.NewBoolVar('%i and %i in %i' % (j1, j2, m)) for j2 in jobs] for j1 in jobs] for m in machines]
precedence = [[[model.NewBoolVar('%i -> %i in %i' % (j1, j2, m)) for j2 in jobs] for j1 in jobs] for m in machines]
for m in machines:
    for j1 in jobs:
        for j2 in jobs:
            if j1 != j2:
                lit = ?
                model.Add(start_vars[m][j2] >= end_vars[m][j1] + setup_matrix[m][j1][j2]).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)

for j in jobs:
    alt_intvs = []
    for m in machines:
        alt_intvs.append(presence_vars[m][j])
    model.Add(cp_model.LinearExpr.Sum(alt_intvs) == 1)

objective = cp_model.LinearExpr.Sum([end_vars[m][j] for j in jobs for m in machines])
model.Minimize(objective)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

# solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = True
solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
status = solver.Solve(model)

for m in machines:
    for j in jobs:
        if solver.Value(presence_vars[m][j]) == 1:
            print('%i in %i, from %i to %i (ptime: %i)' % (j, m, solver.Value(start_vars[m][j]), solver.Value(end_vars[m][j]), processingTimes[m][j]))
```

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two bool_vars as the intervals can be absent/present.

The usual trick is the following:

bool_var a_before_b
model.Add(start(b) >= end(a)).OnlyEnforceIf(a_before_b, present(a), present(b))

bool_var b_before_a
model.Add(start(a) >= end(b)).OnlyEnforceIf(b_before_a, present(a), present(b))

model.AddBoolOr(a_before_b, b_before_a, present(a).Not(), present(b).Not())

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have one more question. If I want to check whether b is positioned right after a (not a -> c -> b), how can I implement it?

Comment: You need the circuit constraint to do the transitive reduction from precedences to successors. Look at jobshop_ft06_distance_sat.py

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I looked at the example and I have another question. The example jobshop_ft06_distance_sat makes a set of arcs. As far as I understand, it is fully connected from a dummy start and makes it a circuit. Is it possible to make alternative arcs? For example, a job can be processed in any machine so I want to make  alternative arcs for all machines.

Comment: Can you Ask another question on s.o. something like transitive réduction from precedences to successors with optional tasks using Cp-sat? The question comes often and deserves some visibility.

Comment: Sure, thank you for your help. I learned a lot from your answer!